# Protect IE6 from exploits when testing?

Tags: security, internet-explorer-6, webbrowser-control, virus, exploit

I wrote an app in C# which uses the webbrowser control. While using it, the site i happen to use it on had an ad that auto DLed and ran itself on my comp causing me to be very annoyed. According to safebrowsing.clients.google.com 2/5000 pages had this exploit, unlucky me.

I use IE6 for testing so what can i do to protect myself from those virus w/o upgrading to IE7+. Will setting the internet security to high solve the problem? (It appears to set every option to disable)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [VPC images that MSFT provides](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef) so if you get pwn3d, you can just blow away the image and start over.